# How to send and receive multiple streams properly

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am trying to make something similiar to teamviewer, my server sends a command to the client, the client starts sending screenshots, i keep showing these in a JLabel, now if my server sends an other command say "stream audio", how can i make my client stream audio too along with the desktop stream (the server should be able to understand the which data is received)? should i use NIO? , I do not understand how NIO's could help in writing multiple outputs and reading mulitiple outputs.

Edit -
For example my server sends a command and the client streams the screen in a new thread and my server again sends a command to get audio and my client starts an other thread to get audio, at this point there are two bytes coming in to the server, how can my server process them correctly?

Comment: NIO will mostly get in the way. You need to send a stream identifier and length before each stream. DataInput/OutputStreams are the way to go.

Comment: @EJP  i use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream, and i convert them to byte[] and send them and recreate the image there, my client/server architecture is that my server accepts replies only if it has sent the client a response, also what datatype identifier shal i use?, will it corrupt the image if i send it along with the image bytes?

Comment: Send it first, along with the length, as I already said. *Before* the image bytes. A short or an int would do for the type, and an int (probably) for the length.

Comment: @EJP , but then my server reads response only after the server sends a command, i have done this because so that if the client disconnects i would get the IOException and i can disconnect, but then if i were to do like that means i  would need to make my server constantly read response and write too, does that mean i must use a seperate thread that would wait for the client to reply and sort things in there ? or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand all of that, but you always need a separate thread per client in blocking I/O.

Comment: @EJP i do have a seperate thread per client but, what i was saying is my code is like this inside each clint thread :- while(isServerRunning){ if(command != null){ send command , read input }  } and if it throws and ioexception while reading or writing it disconnects, so what i was asking is should i make my code inside each client as  Thread waitforreply() = new Thread(-> () { read input, process }); while(isServerRunning) {if(command != null){ send command ) }

Comment: That doesn't agree with your description. You should send a command when you have a command to send, but to read everything the client is sending you need another thread that is permanently in a `read()` loop until disconnection.

Comment: oh i get it, thanks can you post that ill mark that as the answer?, also a quick question is it right to disconnect the client if an IOException is thrown while reading or writing? or could it be because of some other reasons like delays?

Comment: A delay would result in a `SocketTimeoutException` (assuming you have set a timeout on your socket). An `IOException` indicates an error reading or writing to the stream, most likely because the other end disconnected.

Comment: Thanks @BadCash i do not have a timeout on my socket, if i add a timeout will it disconnect if the server doesnt reply or will that timeout be valid while sending data only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a stream identifier and length before each stream. NIO will mostly get in the way. `DataInput/OutputStreams` are the way to go.

A short or an int would do for the type, and an int (probably) for the length.

```
dos.writeShort(type);
dos.writeInt(length);
dos.write(data);
```

and ...

```
int type = dis.readShort();
int length = dis.readInt();
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
dis.readFully(buffer);
```

You should send a command when you have a command to send, but to read everything the client is sending you need another thread that is permanently in a read() loop until disconnection.

> is it right to disconnect the client if an IOException is thrown while reading or writing? or could it be because of some other reasons like delays?

You should close the socket on any `IOException` other than `SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: Thanks @EJP , used short, oh i see, except SocketTimeout okay got it now